# Adding a JButton into a JTable which uses abstract table model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, cellrenderer

I am trying to add a JButton as the first column on the table I created. I did make a research and couldn't find any solution for the tables that use abstract table model.

Here, I create an object array for each record that has texts and boolean variables to have the table render check boxes. Then those object arrays saved into an ArrayList

Here's my code to create my table data.

```
public ArrayList<Object[]> setTableData(){

        /*
        * ItemInfo fields
        **********************
        * line[0] - ReferenceNo
        * line[1] - Quantity
        * line[2] - ItemNameDescriptionSKU
        * line[3] - Cube
        */

        //Setting the data for the table
        ArrayList<Object[]> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<this.itemInfo.size();i++){
            Object[] tempArray = new Object[7];
            tempArray[0] = this.itemInfo.get(i)[1]; //Quantity
            tempArray[1] = this.itemInfo.get(i)[2].toUpperCase(); //Item description
            tempArray[2] = this.itemInfo.get(i)[3]; //Cube
            //This adds charges if the payment type is COD
            //To not to write the charge amount for every row
            //checks the COD type only at the first record of items
            if (i==0 && this.invoice[8].equals("COD"))
                tempArray[3] = this.invoice[22]; //Charges if the invoice type is COD, null otherwise
            else 
                tempArray[3] = " ";

            tempArray[4] = new Boolean (false); //Loaded
            tempArray[5] = new Boolean (false); //Delivered (Will be ignored if pickup)

            itemList.add(tempArray);
        }
        return itemList;
```

Here's my table model

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TicketTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private ArrayList<Object[]> data;
    private boolean isDelivery;
    private String[] columns;


    public TicketTableModel(ArrayList<Object[]> itemInfo, boolean isDelivery){
        super();
        this.data = itemInfo;
        this.isDelivery = isDelivery;
    }
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int i) {

        return this.columns[i];
    }
    public void setColumns ( String[] columns1 ){
        this.columns = columns1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (col < 3)
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data.get(row)[col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {

        return this.data.get(row)[col];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/).

This class implements the render/editor needed to make the button functional. You also provide the `Action` to invoke when the button is pressed.

Comment: The source was very helpful. I am confused because I created the checkboxes using the abstract table model easily. I thought the buttons are the same way. However, it's more complicated than I thought. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The type of `TableModel` is irrelevant.  If you want to "show" a button on a `JTable`, you supply a `TableCellRenderer` (and probably a `TableCellEditor`) for the column which is capable of rendering the button based on the values of the column it represents.

This will mean that your `TableModel` will need to support a column within it's model which represents the button.

Take a closer look at [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer), [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)